# Excel VBA code will crash the document and Outlook intermittently

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have created an inventory tracking excel document that tracks current inventory as well as creating a history of each item on a separate sheet. I use some VBA code to copy the weekly inventory and move it to its history sheet. Everything works, but not the most efficiently as it will cause Excel and Outlook to crash and become unresponsive and eventually have to kill the process in task manager.

I can't figure out how to upload attachments, but here is my below code I use. I am wondering if anyone can point out some issues, or ways to optimize it so it runs more efficiently.

```
Sub Submit_Email()


'to stop flickering when running the macro, and to return back to the start sheet


Dim StartHere As Range

Set StartHere = Selection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



'Copy info for 5440

Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B8:e8").Copy
Sheets("History 5440").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("History 5440").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("History 5440").Range("F5").Copy Sheets("History 5440").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'Copy info for 7450

Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B9:e9").Copy
Sheets("History 7450").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("History 7450").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("History 7450").Range("F5").Copy Sheets("History 7450").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)



'Copy info for 7470


Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B10:e10").Copy
Sheets("History 7470").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("History 7470").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("History 7470").Range("F5").Copy Sheets("History 7470").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)



'Copy info for MBP 15


Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B11:e11").Copy
Sheets("History MBP 15 Retina").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("History MBP 15 Retina").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("History MBP 15 Retina").Range("F5").Copy Sheets("History MBP 15 Retina").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)



'Copy info for MBP 13


Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B12:e12").Copy
Sheets("History MBP 13 Retina").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("History MBP 13 Retina").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("History MBP 13 Retina").Range("F5").Copy Sheets("History MBP 13 Retina").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)










' Sets the variables for each field

Dim TeamMember As String
TeamMember = Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B4")


Dim WeekOf As String
WeekOf = Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B3")

Dim Location As String
Location = Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("A1")



   'if criteria is met, send email to the team

 If Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B10") <= Sheets("Current       Inventory").Range("C10") Or Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("B11") <=   Sheets("Current Inventory").Range("C11") Then


' Select the range of cells on the active worksheet.
 Sheets("Current Inventory").Select Range("A1:E30").Select

' Show the envelope on the ActiveWorkbook.
 ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

 ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
 ' some header text to the email body. It also sets
 ' the To and Subject lines. Finally the message
 ' is sent.
 With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
  .Introduction = Location & " is running low. Please review the below   inventory to see which items are running low so we can be prepared to assist with new hire needs if required."
  .Item.To = "x-inventory-alerts@proofpoint.com;"
  .Item.Subject = Location & " Running Low for the week of " & WeekOf
  .Item.Send
 End With

 ActiveWorkbook.SendMail Recipients:="mcrane@proofpoint.com",   Subject:=Location & " for the week of " & WeekOf & " By " & TeamMember

Else

'otherwise send it to terry only


 ActiveWorkbook.SendMail Recipients:="mcrane@proofpoint.com", Subject:=Location & " for the week of " & WeekOf & " By " & TeamMember

 End If




 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 Application.Goto StartHere

 ActiveWorkbook.Save


'Clear inventory
Range("B8:B18").Select
Selection.ClearContents




End Sub
```

[Current Inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E65R2.png)

Comment: Can you add an image example of your data

Comment: @0m3r I have added a screenshot, Current Inventory. Also, I was running the debugger after removing all the code above ' Sets the variables for each field, and it seems to start hanging up and crashing when the first "With" statement occurs. It hangs for about 15 seconds at the start, then when it comes to the end of the with statement, it crashes. I hope my doc didn't become corrupt....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

at the beginning of your code, and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

at the end of your code? I see you have Screen updating toggled already.

This will turn off screen updating, events, and alerts, causing faster run-time and less possibility of crashing.

Comment: I do have Application.ScreenUpdating = False at the beginning, and True at the end. I will add the EnableEvents and DisplayAlerts to the code as well. Thanks for the tip! I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @MichaelCrane has this fixed your issue?

Comment: Hi Brad, It did not improve the document. It was successful on the first try after adding the code, but the second try caused Excel and Outlook to become unresponsive and have that awesome sound bling when you try to click inside either applications. Had to kill in Task Manager.